# add subtract multiply and divide template functions

Tags: c++, templates

I am trying to find template functions that do:

```
template <typename T>
T add(T lhs, T rhs) {
    return lhs + rhs;
}
```

(for add, subtract, multiply, and divide).

I remember there being a standard set of functions for this-- do you remember what they are?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the header `<functional>`, you'll find things like `std::plus`, `std::minus`, `std::multiplies`, and `std::divides`.

They're not functions, either. They're actually [functors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/356950/c-functors-and-their-uses).

Comment: @BenVoigt, I never noticed that :/

Comment: For example, `plus`'s function call operator is `T  operator()(const  T&  x,  const  T&  y)  const;` but should be `auto operator()(const T& x,  const T& y) const -> declspec(x+y);`  Don't know how that slipped by the committee.  Maybe backward compatibility was deemed more important.

Comment: @BenVoigt +1 Good to know. Is there a functor that does `+=`? If not, maybe it's worth it to write my own set of 8 that do what you recommend.

Comment: @Oliver: I think you'd combine `std::accumulate` with `std::plus`, and it might not be quite as efficient.

Comment: @BenVoigt, If you're interested, you can post an answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11235299/avoid-duplicated-operator-code-by-using-functors

Comment: @chris: I see his other question there, but I think he's asking the wrong question.

Comment: @BenVoigt LOL-- SO is too good! Not only do people answer each others questions, they also *magically know what question they want to ask*! How do you know what question I want to ask? : )

Comment: @Oliver: It seems you want a way to implement your arithmetic operators and compound assignment operators with minimal duplication.  That's a reasonable question, answered in the FAQ (I placed a link in a comment on your other question).  But you asked how to use functors to reduce duplication.  You don't, the solution with functors has more duplication that the method shown in the FAQ.

Answer (score 6):

You need functors such as [std::plus](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/plus) from the `<functional>` header. See **Arithmetic operations** [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional).

These are functors, not functions, so you need an instance to do anything useful:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
int main() {

  std::multiplies<int> m;
  std::cout << m(5,3) << "\n";

}
```

This seems like overkill in the above sample, but they are pretty useful with standard library algorithms. For example, find the product of elements in a vector:

```
std::vector<int> v{1,2,3,4,5,6};
int prod = std::accumulate(v.begin(), v.end(), 1, std::multiplies<int>());
```